# The use of brackets in VIM help pages

Tags: vim, convention, manpage

I'm trying to get into the habit of using VIM help pages, and came across the following line when reading about command-line ranges:

```
/{pattern}[/]   the next line where {pattern} matches     *:/*
```

Now, my understanding of the help-pages syntactic convention is that `[/]` marks an **optional** forward slash character. However, reading further, the following is said about the line above (emphasis mine):

```
The "/" and "?" after {pattern} are **required** to separate the pattern from
anything that follows.
```

Am I misunderstanding the syntactic convention?

Comment: Probably some [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) notation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The "/" and "?" after {pattern} are **required** to separate the pattern from
>   anything that follows.

*If* anything follows (such as an offset, e.g. `/foobar/3` to go to the third line after the match), the `/` after a pattern is required.

Comment: Thank you, this settles it. Out of curiosity, may I ask in which context would something **not** follow the pattern? I was reading about it in the context of the substitute command, in which case the command `s` always follows a pattern.

Comment: In the context of a normal search: `/foo<cr>`. In a substitution command you always need to terminate the substitution with a `/`/`?`

Comment: Oh yeah, of course. Didn't realize that I'm making use of this exact syntax every day :)